# fastest way to make an element in a list as the first element

Tags: c#, list

I have  list and I want a short and fast way to make one of its element as the first.
I have in mind to use the code below to select the 10th element and make it first. But  looking for a better soln

```
tempList.Insert(0, tempList[10]);
tempList.RemoveAt(11);
```

Comment: How much faster do you expect to get?..

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem very bad.

Comment: well I want to make sure that there is no such a code existing in C#, so that I avoid duplicate codes.

Comment: @electricalbah implement it as extension method

Comment: You think that it's such a common use case that there should be a specific function to do this?

Comment: Lists are not really sorted in any way (without user intervention), so I'd imagine this is best way there is... like Jehof said, you can make your own extension method

Comment: You should stick to what you are doing

Comment: If you are bothered with having to find indexes and such you could always use a LinkedList, don't think it would be any performance boost though. tempList.Remove(object); tempList.AddFirst(newobject);

Comment: This feels like a case of pre optimization. Are you sure that this is the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: There is no better way of doing it - all operations that preserve order the way you coded will be `O(n)` if using `List<T>`. To make question reasonable please provide your criteria for "better" - so far "close - need to show minimal understanding of problem".

Answer (score 3):

if you don't mind the ordering of the rest, you actually could swap the two items at position 0 and 10, believe it's better than doing insertion and deletion:

```
var other = tempList[0];
tempList[0]=tempList[10];
tempList[10] = other;
```

and you can even make this an extension of List for ease of use, something like:

```
 public static void Swap<T>(this List<T> list, int oldIndex, int newIndex)
 { 
      // place the swap code here
 }
```

Comment: he does not want to swap. He wants to move the nth element to the first position (front) in the list

Comment: his question is not that clear - he said he wanted to make nth element as the first, but did not say whether he wanted to preserve the ordering of the rest... did i understand correctly? sorry if was wrong - English is not my mother tongue :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some special cases when you could get better performance (for the sake of simplicity, I'm assuming that the value is always inserted before the position where it was taken from):

```
class Program
{
    const int Loops = 10000;
    const int TakeLoops = 10;
    const int ItemsCount = 100000;
    const int Multiplier = 500;
    const int InsertAt = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tempList = new List<int>();
        var tempDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemsCount; i++)
        {
            tempList.Add(i);
            tempDict.Add(i, i);
        }

        var limit = 0;
        Stopwatch
            sG = new Stopwatch(),
            s1 = new Stopwatch(),
            s2 = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan
            t1 = new TimeSpan(),
            t2 = new TimeSpan();

        for (int k = 0; k < TakeLoops; k++)
        {
            var takeFrom = k * Multiplier + InsertAt;
            s1.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < Loops; i++)
            {
                tempList.Insert(InsertAt, tempList[takeFrom]);
                tempList.RemoveAt(takeFrom + 1);
            }
            s1.Stop();
            t1 += s1.Elapsed;
            s2.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < Loops; i++)
            {
                var e = tempDict[takeFrom];
                for (int j = takeFrom - InsertAt; j > InsertAt; j--)
                {
                    tempDict[InsertAt + j] = tempDict[InsertAt + j - 1];
                }
                tempDict[InsertAt] = e;
            }
            s2.Stop();
            t2 += s2.Elapsed;
            if (s2.Elapsed > s1.Elapsed || limit == 0)
                limit = takeFrom;
        }

        sG.Start();
        for (int k = 0; k < TakeLoops; k++)
        {
            var takeFrom = k * Multiplier + InsertAt;
            if (takeFrom >= limit)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Loops; i++)
                {
                    tempList.Insert(InsertAt, tempList[takeFrom]);
                    tempList.RemoveAt(takeFrom + 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Loops; i++)
                {
                    var e = tempDict[takeFrom];
                    for (int j = takeFrom - InsertAt; j > InsertAt; j--)
                    {
                        tempDict[InsertAt + j] = tempDict[InsertAt + j - 1];
                    }
                    tempDict[InsertAt] = e;
                }
            }
        }
        sG.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List:       {0}", t1);
        Console.WriteLine("Dictionary: {0}", t2);
        Console.WriteLine("Optimized:  {0}", sG.Elapsed);

        /***************************
        List:       00:00:11.9061505
        Dictionary: 00:00:08.9502043
        Optimized:  00:00:08.2504321
        ****************************/
    }
}
```

In the example above, a `Dictionary<int,int>` is being used to store the index of each element. You will get better results if the gap between `insertAt` and `takeFrom` is smaller. As this interval increases, the performance will degrade. I guess you might want to evaluate this gap and take the optimal branch based on it's value.

Comment: Why not `var e = tempDict[10];`? Besides of that: I cannot believe this is faster than using insert/remove in some way. Internally those methods copy an array which is normally well supported by the runtime.

Comment: You are right, updated. The test says it's faster up to some `[insertAt,takeFrom]` interval size.